# When I am querying from postgresql for the first time, It's providing me null value but after waiting for some time the same query is giving me result

Tags: java, sql, postgresql, jdbc, junit

When I am querying from postgresql for the first time, It's providing me null value but after waiting for some time the same query is giving me result.  I have added a dummy code of what I am trying and what I am getting.

Could it be some kind of caching? If so, How can I overcome it.

```
        Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver");

         // Establish a connection to the database
         String url = "jdbc:postgresql://path-to-database";
         String user = "myusername";
         String password = "mypassword";
         Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, password);

         String query = "SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE column1 = 'value1'";
         ResultSet resultSet = statement.executeQuery(query);

         while (resultSet.next()) {
            String column2 = resultSet.getString("column2");
            System.out.println(column2);
         }

         Thread.sleep(100000); //wait for 100 seconds

         resultSet = statement.executeQuery(query);
         while (resultSet.next()) {
            String column2 = resultSet.getString("column2");
            System.out.println(column2);
         }
```

Output:

```
null
myValue
```

Comment: Your code isn't complete, how's statement variable declared?

Comment: PostgreSQL doesn't offer a broken caching layer.  If you have gone out of your way to introduce one, you haven't told us about it, so we can't tell you about it.